# UIView Animation in Swift not working, wrong arguments error

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to do an animation and used the below code. I'm getting **"Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type '(FloatLiteralConvertible, delay: FloatLiteralConvertible, options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: () -> () -> $T4, completion: (Bool) -> (Bool) -> $T5)'" Error**.

This means I'm using wrong arguments. I could be wrong. Please help in this. I couldn't really resolve it.

```
var basketTopFrame = CGRect()
basketTopFrame = dropPlace.frame
var mytimer : NSTimer = NSTimer .scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "restart", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn , animations: {  var pickPlace = basketTopFrame }, completion:  {(finished: Bool) in mytimer })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Completion block expect a return type void. You are providing _NSTimer_ object. Use this; UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn , animations: {  var pickPlace = basketTopFrame }, completion:  {(finished: Bool) in mytimer.invalidate() })

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Closures have auto return if there is only one statement. Due to that in your case it is returning `NSTimer` and not `Void`. Your provided closure doesn't match signature closure. You have to call method on `myTimer`, for example, to fix this issue:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn,
    animations: {
        var pickPlace = basketTopFrame
    },
    completion:  { (finished: Bool) in
        mytimer.fire()
    }
)
```