# Cannot invoke animateWithDuration with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2

I am trying to use JSSAlertView ([github.com/stakes/JSSAlertView](http://github.com/stakes/JSSAlertView)) with Swift 2.0 but I have an error :

```
Cannot invoke animateWithDuration with an argument list of type '(Double, delay: Double, usingSpringWithDampling: Double, initialSpringVelocity: Double, options: nil, animations () -> _, completion: (Bool) -> _)'
```

for the code :

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.05, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: nil, animations: {
        self.containerView.center = self.rootViewController.view.center
        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
    })
```

I saw this two answers :
[Nested closures does not like argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022052/nested-closures-does-not-like-argument-list)
[UIView Animation in Swift not working, wrong arguments error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397164/uiview-animation-in-swift-not-working-wrong-arguments-error)
but they don't help me.

I still think that the problem comes either from the "animations" or the "completion".

Comment: dampling ➝ damping. did you re type this or copy and paste it?

Comment: @nielsbot I retyped, my mistake sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting in Swift 2, option sets are not `nil`-convertible anymore, so you can't use `nil`. However, they are array literal convertible (for an array of options to be OR'd together), so you can use `[]` for no options.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a different `options` than `nil`. For example `.CurveEaseInOut`:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.05, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
    self.containerView.center = self.rootViewController.view.center
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
})
```